# React strict mode and React Query cause data duplication?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern

`Hi. Why on earth does this happen? I provide my api route and client code so that you can see it clearer.
The thing is that when I don't use React Query and have strict mode turned off things are ok but React Query messes things up. Sometimes when i leave the page and come back to it I see instead of things start from scratch, some duplicate data is there and sometimes data is not shown in the right order.
by strict mode I mean:
<React.StrictMode>
Thank you

server:

```
module.exports.showLikedPosts = async (req, res) => {
  getUser(req); // auth
  const posts = await Post.find({
    $and: [
      { likers: { $in: req.params.userId } },
      { blockedBy: { $nin: req.params.userId } },
      { blocked: { $nin: req.params.userId } },
    ]
  })
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .skip(req.params.n)
    .limit(3)
    .select("-blocked -blockedBy");
  let end = 0;
  if (posts.length === 0) end = 1;
  res.json({ posts, end });
};
```

client:

```
export const LikedPosts = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const [likedPosts, setLikedPosts] = useState([]);
  const [authoFetch, setAutoFetch] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState(true);

  const { data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: [{ savedPosts: id }],
    enabled: authoFetch,
    queryFn: ({ signal }) =>
      showLikedPosts({
        signal,
        userId: id,
        token,
        n: page
      }),
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setLikedPosts(prev => [...prev, ...data.posts])
      setPage(p=>p+3)
      setAutoFetch(false)
    }
    if (data && data.end === 1) {
      toast.success("Yep, that's all")
      setHasNextPage(false);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>My liked posts</div>
      {likedPosts.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <br />
          {likedPosts.map((i) => (
            <Link key={i._id} to={`/profiles/${i.poster}/posts/${i._id}`}>
              <img src={i.images[0].url} alt="" className="big-square" />
              <hr />
            </Link>
          ))}
         
        </div>
      )}
      {likedPosts.length === 0 && (
        <>
          <div>No items</div>
        </>
      )}
      <Waypoint onEnter={()=>{
        hasNextPage && refetch()
        }}>
        <h5 className="text-muted mt-5">
          Loading data{" "}
        
        </h5>
      </Waypoint>
    </>
  );
};
```

fetch api:

```
export async function showLikedPosts({ signal, userId, token, n }) {

  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/posts/showLikedPosts/${userId}/${n}`,
    {
      signal,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': token,
      },
    }
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = new Error("An error occurred");
    error.code = response.status;
    error.info = await response.json();
    throw error;
  }

  return response.json();
}
```

I tried the code w/o useQuery and strict mode and it worked. but I want useQuery and strict mode.